# What commonly used hotkeys exist on OS X?

Tags: mac, shortcut

Recently began using a mac, but am not familiar with all of the hot keys. Many of them just use Command + key instead of control + key, but not all.

What are some useful, non-application-specific hot keys that anyone could use?  Is there a list of system wide keyboard shortcuts, and how can I find other shortcuts for applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some resources to get you started.  As a Mac user who likes to know the fastest way to do things, I approve these links. The first link ought to cover you for most things. I've copied in some highlights. The lists are quite thorough for non-application-specific shortcuts.

### http://www.danrodney.com/mac/

#### From any application

• Switch between open applications: Cmd + Tab
• Do the above, but in reverse: Add Shift (Cmd + Tab + Shift)
• Quit an application from the Application Switcher: while holding Cmd, type q.
• Switch between windows in an open application: Cmd + Tilde (~)
• Cmd+H will immediately hide an application from view. Just in case, y'know.

#### Finder-specific shortcuts

• Go to parent folder: Cmd + Up Arrow
• Use space to quickly preview any file in the Finder
• Move something to the Trash: Cmd + Delete
• Empty your trash from anywhere: Shift + Cmd + Delete

### http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343

• Hold the power button to force your computer to shut down. That's for if it freezes / becomes totally unresponsive.
• Take a screenshot: Cmd + Shift + 3
• Click and drag to capture a selection of the screen, or hit Space to take a screenshot of a particular window: Cmd + Shift + 4
• Hit Cmd + Space to do a quick-search sort of thing with OSX's Spotlight.
•

### [The Huffington Post tries to make shortcuts cute](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/04/14/keyboard-shortcuts-mac_n_4981493.html)

### [Listicle 1](http://www.maclife.com/article/features/10_coolest_keyboard_shortcuts_you_never_knew_about), [Listicle 2](http://www.maclife.com/article/features/10_coolest_keyboard_shortcuts_you_never_knew_about)

Answer (score 2):

Shortcuts are often displayed next to their relevant menu item if you are using menus (not so much if you are using icons in an app).  You can just open up many apps and peruse the menus looking for shortcuts that exist that may be useful.

Another method is to use the app [CheatSheet](http://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/), this is a free app that essentially goes around hunting for shortcuts that have been officially defined/declared by an app, and when you hold down the <kbd>Command</kbd> key for more than a second or so it will present a list of whatever it knows about for the currently active application, allowing you to then complete the shortcut action without having to let for of the key.  A great way to find and learn them, or remind yourself of uncommonly used ones without having to mouse up to the menus.

[image: CheatSheet Screenshot]